# What is a function composition algorithm that will work for multiple arguments, such as h(x,y) . f(x) . g(x) = h(f(x),g(x))?

Tags: function, functional-programming, composition, currying

For example, suppose we had the functions `double(x) = 2 * x`, `square(x) = x ^ 2` and `sum(x,y) = x + y`. What is a function `compose` such as `compose(compose(sum, square), double) = x^2 + 2*x`? Notice that I'm asking a function that can be used for functions of any arity. For example, you could compose `f(x,y,z)` with `g(x)`, `h(x)`, `i(x)` into `f(g(x), h(x), i(x))`.

Comment: Is this for a particular language?

Comment: You just defined the function you're asking for, so I don't know what you need here.

Comment: I'm asking for a high-order function that does what I did here (manually) to any functions (automatically).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a common Haskell idiom, [applicative functors](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Applicative.html#t%3aApplicative):

```
composed = f <$> g1 <*> g2 <*> ... <*> gn
```

(A nicer introduction can be found [here](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids#applicative-functors)).

This looks very clean because of automatic partial application, and works like this:

```
(<*>) f g x = f x (g x)
(<$>) f g x = f (g x) -- same as (.)
```

For example,

```
f <$> g <*> h <*> i ==>
(\x -> f (g x)) <*> h <*> i ==>
(\y -> (\x -> f (g x)) y (h y)) <*> i ==>
(\y -> f (g y) (h y)) <*> i ==>
(\z -> (\y -> f (g y) (h y)) z (i z)) ==>
(\z -> f (g z) (h z) (i z)).
```

Applicative functors are more general, though. They are not an "algorithm", but a *concept*. You could also do the same on a tree, for example (if properly defined):

```
(+) <$> (Node (Leaf 1) (Leaf 2)) <*> (Node (Leaf 3) (Leaf 4)) ==>
Node (Leaf 4) (Leaf 6)
```

But I doubt that applicatives are really usable in most other languages, due to the lack of easy partial application.

Comment: Haskell is really awesome. I upvoted but will need some time to understand what's going on there. Thanks you!

Comment: @Dokkat great to hear that. Just ask if I should clarify on something.

Comment: j has trains: `(f g h) x` is `f(g(x), h(x))` or `(g x) f h x` in j notation. They are very useful. For example the mean of a list is `mean =: (+/ % #)`  which would be `mean = (/) <$> sum <*> len` in Haskell with the obvious `sum`, `len`.