# Create a function that returns the logical OR of several boolean predicates

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Suppose I have in my code a number of boolean predicates defined:

```
def pred1[A](x: A): Boolean = { ... }
def pred2[A](x: A): Boolean = { ... }
def pred3[A](x: A): Boolean = { ... }
```

Now, I'd like to be able to create a function that is, for example, the logical OR of `pred1` and `pred3`.

So, something like:

```
def pred1Or3[A](x: A) = or(pred1, pred2)
```

Even better, it'd be nice to be able to generalize so that I could provide my own combining function. So, if instead, I wanted to have the logical AND, I'd call:

```
def pred1And3[A](x: A) = combine({_ && _}, pred1, pred2)
```

I can achieve the same basic effect this way:

```
def pred1And3[A](x: A) = Seq(pred1, pred2) map { _(x) } reduce { _ && _ }
```

but that seems a little verbose and clouds the intent. Is there a simpler way to do this in Scala?

Comment: [Applicatives](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13437773/1346276) solve the general case, though I'm not sure if they can be implemented in Scala.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a solution that is simple and allows a variable number of items to be passed at the same time.  I've given both the `or` case and the more generic `combine` case:

```
def or[A](ps: (A => Boolean)*) = 
  (a: A) => ps.exists(_(a))

def combine[A](ps: (A => Boolean)*)(op: (Boolean, Boolean) => Boolean) = 
  (a: A) => ps.map(_(a)).reduce(op)
```

Here's some example usage:

```
// "or" two functions
val pred1or3 = or(pred1, pred3)                
pred1or3("the")

// "or" three functions
val pred12or3 = or(pred1, pred2, pred3)        
pred12or3("the")

// apply a dijoined rule directly
or(pred1, pred2, pred3)("the")                 

// combine two functions with "and"
val pred12and3 = combine(pred1, pred3)(_ && _) 
pred12and3("the")

// apply a conjoined rule directly
combine(pred1, pred2, pred3)(_ && _)("the")    

// stack functions as desired (this is "(pred1 || pred3) && (pred1 || pred2)")
combine(or(pred1, pred3), or(pred1, pred2))(_ && _)("a")
```

Comment: This kind of solution is exactly what I had in mind. I would definitely want the ability to combine a variable number of predicates. However, I'm surprised that this isn't already present in Scala.

Comment: Hi Mark! Oh it is, however its well hidden in Scala's functional programming library: scalaz, examples and explanations can be found here: http://voidmainargs.blogspot.de/2012/02/having-fun-with-monoid-in-scalaz-seven.html?m=1

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution that I've used in the past:

```
implicit def wrapPredicates[A](f: A => Boolean) = new {
  def <|>(g: A => Boolean) = (x: A) => f(x) || g(x)
  def <&>(g: A => Boolean) = (x: A) => f(x) && g(x)
}
```

Use as follows:

```
val pred12or3 = pred1 <|> pred2 <|> pred3
```

Comment: This is an interesting and flexible approach. It introduces what I'd like to call the "monogram and" and "monogram or" operators.

Comment: That's perfect. Exactly what i wanted to do. But what do you mean `in the past`? Did you find something better?

Answer (score 2):

Here's one solution that fails fast, but isn't as generic:

```
def or[A](ps: (A => Boolean)*) = (a:A) => ps.exists(_(a))
def and[A](ps: (A => Boolean)*) = (a:A) => ps.forall(_(a))
```

## Sample session

```
scala> def or[A](ps: (A => Boolean)*) = (a:A) => ps.exists(_(a))
or: [A](ps: A => Boolean*)A => Boolean 
scala> or((x:Int) => {println("a");x > 5}, (x:Int) => {println("b");x < 2})
res6: Int => Boolean = <function1>    
scala> res6(1)
a
b
res7: Boolean = true    
scala> res6(6)
a
res8: Boolean = true
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def or[A](p: A => Boolean, q: A => Boolean) = (a: A) => p(a) || q(a)
def logic[A](p: A => Boolean, q: A => Boolean)(c: (Boolean, Boolean) => Boolean) = {
  (a: A) => c( p(a) , q(a) )
}
```

You could add a parameter `(a: A)` to these methods instead of returning a function, e.g.:

```
def or2[A](a: A)(p: A => Boolean, q: A => Boolean) = p(a) || q(a)
```