# How to make it point-free when there is local variable?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, lodash, pointfree

I have a code snippet to remove the host part from server URL in OpenAPI definition. I don't know how to make it point-free totally. (It isn't necessary to do that. But I just want to know how to.)

The difficult part to me is to get rid of the local variable `idx`. I read this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16930860/94148) and it seems that `ap` can solve. I didn't try because there is no `ap` in lodash.

```
const convert = _.flow([
  _.split('/'),
  (segments) => {
    const idx = _.findLastIndex(containAny(['{', '}', ':']))(segments);
    return _.drop(idx+1, segments);
  },
  _.reject(_.isEmpty),
  _.join('/'),
  path => '/' + path,
]);
```

Full code:

```
const _ = require('lodash/fp');

const urls = [
  'http://localhost:8080/petstore/v1',
  '//localhost/petstore/v1',
  '{server}/batch-service/api/batches/lwm2m/v1',
  'https://{server}/batch-service/api/batches/lwm2m/v1',
  '/batch-service/api/batches/lwm2m/v1',
  '/',
]

const containAny = patterns => str => _.some(pattern => _.includes(pattern, str), patterns);

const convert = _.flow([
  _.split('/'),
  (segments) => {
    const idx = _.findLastIndex(containAny(['{', '}', ':']))(segments);
    return _.drop(idx+1, segments);
  },
  _.reject(_.isEmpty),
  _.join('/'),
  path => '/' + path,
]);

_.map(convert)(urls);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case you need to call `_.findLastIndex()` on `segments`, and then call `_.drop()` on the results of the find and `segments`:

```
drop(findLastIndex(segments))(segments)
```

Which is equivalent to the [chain combinator](https://gist.github.com/Avaq/1f0636ec5c8d6aed2e45) function:

```
const chain = f => g => x => f(g(x))(x);
```

Lodash/fp accepts all functions when using `_.flow()` (which is also a functional combinator), so you can create other functional combinators, and use them.

```js
const chain = f => g => x => f(g(x))(x);

const containAny = patterns => str => _.some(pattern => _.includes(pattern, str), patterns);

const findLastSegmentIndex = _.flow(
  _.findLastIndex(containAny(['{', '}', ':'])),
  _.add(1)
)

const convert = _.flow([
  _.split('/'),
  chain(_.drop)(findLastSegmentIndex),
  _.reject(_.isEmpty),
  _.join('/'),
  path => '/' + path,
]);

const urls = [
  'http://localhost:8080/petstore/v1',
  '//localhost/petstore/v1',
  '{server}/batch-service/api/batches/lwm2m/v1',
  'https://{server}/batch-service/api/batches/lwm2m/v1',
  '/batch-service/api/batches/lwm2m/v1',
  '/',
];

const result = _.map(convert)(urls);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)'></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd need `converge`, which `lodash` doesn't have, but Ramda has.
It applies different functions to the same argument and then uses the result of these applications as arguments for another given function.

```js
const convert = _.flow([
  _.split('/'),
  R.converge(_.drop, [_.flow([_.findLastIndex(containAny(['{', '}', ':'])), add(1)]), _.identity]),
  _.reject(_.isEmpty),
  _.join('/'),
  path => '/' + path,
]);
```

https://ramdajs.com/docs/#converge

Comment: Do you miss a `)` after `add(1)`? And also, lodash/fp _.flow() accepts array rather then multiple arguments.